# GraphQL query using _id String, with Object ID stored in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, graphql

Having trouble getting my graphql query to return anything when sending the _id as a string. If instead, I query the DB using any other stored key (for example, name: "Account 1"), it works great and returns the object. My Account schema uses type: GraphQLString for the _id, but i've also tried using GraphQLID and neither have been successful.

```
const AccountType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Account',
    fields: () => ({
        _id: { type: GraphQLString },
        name: { type: GraphQLString },
        balance: { type: GraphQLInt },
    })
});

const RootQuery = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'RootQueryType',
    fields: {
        getAccounts: {
            type: AccountType,
            args: { _id: { type: GraphQLString } },
            async resolve(parentValue, args, context) {
                console.log(args._id)
                return context.mongo.Accounts.findOne({ _id: args._id })
                    .then(response => console.log(response))
            }
        }
    }
});
```

In my MongoDB collection, the _id is stored as Object IDs. Wondering if it doesn't recognize the string as the Object ID stored? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can also remove the underscore from ```_id``` since mongodb is able to successfully parse it

Answer (score 0):

Solution: mongo was not able to query the object with the _id as a string. I had to require a method to convert it to an Object ID.

```
const ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
let _idObject = ObjectId(args._id)
```